# libnotify, PKG_CONFIG_PATH

Tags: libnotify, pkg-config

I am installing spidermonkey on Ubuntu 11.10. When running ./configure I receive a dependency error that libnotify >= 0.4 is not met.

Located the package in Ubuntu as

```
gir1.2-notify-0.7
```

So then I found out where it was installed.

```
renshaw@renshaw-TravelMate-5740G:~/spidermonkey$ dpkg -L gir1.2-notify-0.7
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-notify-0.7
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-notify-0.7/copyright
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/girepository-1.0
/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Notify-0.7.typelib
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-notify-0.7/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-notify-0.7/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/gir1.2-notify-0.7/changelog.Debian.gz
```

So then I have attempted to add this to PKG_CONFIG_PATH with

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/:/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Notify-0.7.typelib
```

However I still receive the error.

```
configure: error: Library requirements (libnotify >= 0.4) not met;
```

How can I get `./configure` to see libnotify as gir1.2-notify-0.7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the `*-dev` packages if you need to compile something using that library.

In your case you need `libnotify-dev`. Install it (`sudo apt install libnotify-dev`) and run `./configure` again.

Comment: For RHEL I got it from here: `yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libnotify-devel-0.7.7-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`